# Tracking in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, tracking

After tracking camera and clicking on one of the tracker points, I added "null and camera" then I attached a picture to it.

So I want the picture to be steady in a place when I move my recording camera, but the picture shakes in every frame.The film itself doesn't have any shake but the picture is not steady. I think the problem is with the tracker but what is it?

Help me.

Comment: Welcome sa_std :) Please add an image or re-phrase your question in order to get a solid answer. At the moment it's only *guessing* for such complex topic. Anyway, enjoy video.SE!

Answer (score 2):

A few things to try:

Make sure your camera footage is at the same frames per second as your comp.

Instead of selecting a single track point, try drawing a lassoo around several points.  You'll get a target plane instead.  Make sure it's facing the right way (if it's not - redraw your lassoo around some different points).

Open the Advanced triangle in the camera tracker's effects settings, and check the box marked "Detailed Analysis".

Make sure you do your tracking at 100% zoom level in the display.  (This definitely used to cause issues - maybe they've fixed it now).

If there's something weird in your footage that will damage the tracking quality, try masking it out and precomping the footage before you start tracking.

Hope it helps.